# Making h3 element take the space as text inside it

Tags: html, css

My requirement is to make an `h3` element take up only that amount of space as the text in it. Can't use `span` directly. I tried encapsulating `h3` element with `span` but it didn't work. The red color should have only the width as the text hello world.

HTML code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <h3 class="center">hello world</h3>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.parent {
    padding-left:5px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:blue;
}

.center {
    text-align:center;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/845nLfcu/)

Comment: h3 is a `block` element which cannot fulfill your demands, you will aither have to float-wrap it, or use a `inline-block`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
.center {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pn89b1c8/

Adding `text-align:center` to the `.parent` div will then center the h3 inside of the `.parent`.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply inline layout to the `h3.center` element (for example, `inline-block`). If you want to center `h3` after this, you can apply `text-align: center` to the `.parent`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/845nLfcu/3/)

Answer (score 3):

you can use a span element instead of h3,but if you want a h3, just add this line, it will although remove the centering

```
display:inline-block;
```

and if you want to center it, then add

```
text-align:center
```

to the parent div css

Answer (score 1):

You can't use span? What if I use not a span?

```css
.parent {
    padding-left:5px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:blue;
}

.center {
    text-align:center;
    overflow:auto;
    
}
notaspan{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h3 class="center"><notaspan>hello world</notaspan></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like everybody is suggesting to use inline block, well you could use this too.

```css
.parent {
    background-color:blue;
}
.center {
    background-color:aqua;
    display:table; /*shrink to fit width*/
    margin:auto; /*center it*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h3 class="center">hello world</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like an overkill for this exact issue. _But surely a working one_.

Comment: @suslov what do you mean by overkill it? it's better to have some diversities, rather than repeating all the same answer, again and again... no?

Comment: My point isn't that this _solution is bad_, just from my point of view, desired result can be achieved using more orthodox tools, that's it. No offense, anyway.

Comment: @suslov anyway, I think OP will accept your answer, as it's the first post that suggesting inline block, and it makes sense too.

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {    
        text-align:center;
        overflow:auto;
        background-color:red;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

With this, you don't need to change your html or display settings. If setting absolute to h3 causes problems, you can set .parent to relative. You can even remove `text-align:center;` I believe.